# How Can I Fetch Every Member On Particular Sever ? In Discord.js V13

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord, discord.js

My code so far:

```
const guild = bot.guilds.cache.find((g) => g.id === id);

guild.members
  .fetch()
  .then((members) =>
    members.forEach((member) => console.log(member.user.username)),
  );
```

This no longer works in V13:

Comment: Log `guild` to make sure a valid guild returns. Add a `catch()` block to the `fetch()` promise. Ensure you have the guild members intent enabled